# 'Bot' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol in Pycord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

So i was working in the cogs of a local hosted discord bot, when i tried to run it it displayed the following error:

```
async with client:
TypeError: 'Bot' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol
```

The main file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='Escribe "/" para ver los comandos'))
    print(f'Bot conectado como {client.user}')
    print('ID: {}'.format(client.user.id))

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
            print(f"{filename[:-3]} está cargado!")

async def main():
    async with client:
        await load()
        await client.run(TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I tried to create a copy and do exactly what the documentation and tutorials did but it remained the same,
i tried to update the libraries and didn't work either so i'm pretty much stuck here. Thanks in advance for any insight of my problem.
A paste of the full log [here](https://pastebin.com/zpCcixxV)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Hi, i'm using python 3.11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't been working with cogs, I tried it myself to see what I could do and found out that you don't necessarily have to load the cogs before you run the bot. This might be a sloppy solution, but it will do the job.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")


async def load_cogs(client):
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
            print(f"{filename[:-3]} está cargado!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():

    await load_cogs(client) # loading the cogs after the bot has initiated
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='Escribe "/" para ver los comandos'))
    
    print(f'Bot conectado como {client.user}')
    print('ID: {}'.format(client.user.id))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I tried running it along with the cogs and it kinda works in the main file but the commands in the cogs file don't.

Comment: Are you sure the cogs are written properly?

Comment: After some tinkering i was able to use your solution along with the cogs