# Discord.py Cog Problem at Server (the asynchronous context manager protocol)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm developing a discord bot on VSCode, and using [huguitis nodes](https://dash.huguitisnodes.host/servers) panel to make it run 7/24.

I newly added cogs to the bot with the same commands, and it works on my pc, at VSCode terminal. But when i try to run the same code on server, i get this error on terminal:

```
 warn(message, DistributionWarning, stacklevel=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 93, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 89, in main
    async with bot:
TypeError: 'Bot' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol
```

My main.py Cog codes:

```
async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

async def main():
    async with bot:
        await load()
        await bot.start('ODY3MzIyMDMwMzIzOTI1MDIz.GyYxqx.628pkxcehVTwEqKK55rsVPtAPaAP00Vu26iyJs')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Connection command in my Cog files:

```
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(example(bot))
```

I saw a trick from another flow, tried to run the bot first and loading the cogs when the bot is ready. It didn't work.

What can i do to fix it? Don't tell me to use print to see the problem, its not about it. The code works in my computer.

Comment: There's another post about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76606967/bot-object-does-not-support-the-asynchronous-context-manager-protocol-in-pycor). Does this help you?

Comment: yea i saw it , there is no solution there, the topic is the same but he realized that his problem is not about that error. i'm already using the codes that he used to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Allright Guys. I fixed it.

Previously i was using nextcord, and i realized that i didn't uninstall it.

And when i use 'pip > freeze requirements.txt' command, it was adding nextcord to requirements file.

So i uninstalled nextcord, and re-installed discord.py to fix it.

thanks for help!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).